# Proof for a question regarding order of $n$-tuples of real numbers

Tags: proof-writing, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, order-theory

[Question as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opAYt.png)

Let $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3,..., x_n)$ and $y= (y_1, y_2, y_3,..., y_n),$ where $x_1, x_2, x_3,..., x_n ,y_1, y_2, y_3,..., y_n$ are real numbers.

We write **$x > y$** if, for some $k$, $1 \le k \le (n-1)$,

$x_1 = y_1$, $x_2 = y_2$, $x_3 = y_3$, ...,  $x_k= y_k$ but $x_{k+1} > y_{k+1}$.

Show that for $u = ( u_1,..., u_n)$, $v = ( v_1,..., v_n)$, $w = ( w_1,..., w_n)$, $z = ( z_1,..., z_n)$, if **$u > v$** and **$w > z$**, then **$(u+w) > (v+z)$.**

I have lots of doubts. Does $(u+w)$ mean that I add each corresponding $i$th element of the sets and thus have still $n$ elements in $(u+w)$ or does it mean that I just put together all the elements from each of the set and then arrange it ascendingly to have $2n$ elements?
If it is the latter, then I think we can just prove that elements $( u_{k+1} +  w_{n+1} ) > (v_{k+1} +  z_{n+1}),$ hence get the sets also in that inequality for some $m \le k+n$. I am not sure what topic this problem which might have helped. It is from a general problems book for a competitive exam.
Can anyone please help me with this problem? Thanks.
I am having trouble with Mathjax, so I have also attached an image with the right formatting.

Comment: Yes, you are treating u and w as "vectors" and the sum is "coordinatewise": u+ w= (u1+ w1, u2+ w2, …). The order defined here, "u< w", is only a "partial order".  Most u and v are "not comparable"- that is, neither u< v nor v< u is true.

Comment: There is no inequality or equality defined between u and w. Its adding those two sets.

Comment: @user247327 Isn't < lexicographic order, which is a linear order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $1 \le k_1 \le n - 1$ be such that $u_i = v_i$ for all $1 \le i \le k_1$ but $u_{k_1 + 1} \gt v_{k_1 + 1}$. Also, let $1 \le k_2 \le n - 1$ be such that $w_i = z_i$ for all $1 \le i \le k_2$ but $w_{k_2 + 1} \gt z_{k_2 + 1}$. Next, we have the following $3$ cases to consider:

$$k_1 \lt k_2 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$k_1 = k_2 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
$$k_1 \gt k_2 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

To make somewhat easier to discuss, let $a = u + w$, so $a_i = u_i + w_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$, and $b = v + z$, so $b_i = v_i + z_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$. With \eqref{eq1}, we have that $a_i = b_i$ for all $1 \le i \le k_1$. However, for $i = k_1 + 1$, we have that $u_{k_1 + 1} \gt v_{k_1 + 1}$, but $w_{k_1 + 1} = z_{k_1 + 1}$, so $a_{k_1 + 1} \gt b_{k_1 + 1}$. A similar situation occurs for \eqref{eq3}, but with $k_1$ and $k_2$ switched around.

Thus, the final case to consider is \eqref{eq2}, where I let $k = k_1 = k_2$. In this case, we still have that $a_i = b_i$ for all $1 \le i \le k$. Also, both $u_{k + 1} \gt v_{k + 1}$ and $w_{k + 1} \gt z_{k + 1}$, so $a_{k + 1} \gt b_{k + 1}$.

In all $3$ cases, we have that $a \gt b$, i.e., $\left(u + w\right) \gt \left(v + z\right)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This resolves my question. So indeed we consider them as vectors and not as sets.

Comment: @DS112 You are welcome. Yes, we need to consider them as vectors. Note that sets are unordered, so you can't do things like impose ordering conditions, i.e., $=$ or $\gt$, on elements at specific indices. Also, using round brackets indicates they are vectors, as sets are usually indicated using brace brackets.